# Why isn't my if statement working with get_the_category?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to make an if statement that would echo a word for each category that the post is in, it gets the category name from the post id, but the first category is All Stories so I asked it to get the second category that the post is in:

```
$category_detail=get_the_category( $post->ID )[1]->name;
echo $category_detail;
// echoes COMPANY NEWS
if($category_detail == "COMPANY NEWS") {
    echo "C_News";
} elseif ($category_detail == "SECTOR OPPORTUNITIES") {
    echo "S_News";
}
```

but the result is the C_News after every post category even if it's not the right category.

[image]
[image]

I tried using is_category( 'Company News' ) but that didn't work, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a **comparison** (`==`) instead of an **assignment** (`=`):

```
$category_detail=get_the_category( $post->ID )[1]->name;
echo $category_detail;
// echoes COMPANY NEWS
if($category_detail == "COMPANY NEWS") {
    echo "C_News";
} elseif ($category_detail == "SECTOR NEWS") {
    echo "S_News";
}
```

Your code (`if ($category_detail = "COMPANY NEWS")`) is always true as it is an **assignment**, therefore it will always echo the `COMPANY NEWS` branch.

Comment: No luck doesn't display anything at all.

Comment: @MrJoshFisher: What is in `$category_detail` (the exact value). Additionally, are there any whitespaces?

Comment: using echo $category_detail; only echoes "COMPANY NEWS", different result for different posts obviously.

Comment: @MrJoshFisher this is the correct answer. You need double equal signs. It would also help to use strtolower() on both values so you know they will have a better chance of being equal since case doesn't seem to matter

Comment: @rasclatt tried using strtolower() but the css is causing it to be uppercase the result without css is simply company news, but I also tried changing "COMPANY NEWS" to "company news" but still no luck.

Comment: @MrJoshFisher You only use `strtolower()` in the comparison, not the output

Comment: @MrJoshFisher If you have done these things (you could also trim() as well) and it still doesn't work, then double check your spelling or look closer at `$category_detail` to make sure it's outputting what you expect.

Comment: SOLVED - The $category_detail echoes "Company News", the css on the front made it all CAPS, changed to be if($category_detail == "Company News") {echo " C_News";} and that works :)

Comment: This answer also told me to be aware of the comparison operators == not =

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I can see is that you need to use a comparison operator ("==") instead of setting the $category_detail variable with ("="). Make sure you're changing that in BOTH places.

Also note that the wordpress coding standards say your comparison should have the variable on the right, that way if you ever mis-type it or something else goes wonky the operation fails and throws an error instead of ALWAYS returning true.

Example:

```
if( "Company News" == $category_detail ){
    echo "hello world";
}
```

Comment: I swapped the comparison operator to == and for the fun of it I switched it so it was if( "Company News" == $category_detail ) but still no luck.

Comment: Try a strict comparison?

    if( "company news" === $category_detail )

Also, the == comparison is case sensitive. You could try setting both values to lower or upper case for an accurate comparison.